# How to use the *highlight function* to highlight an Item in a ListView?

Tags: react-native

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could give an example to show how to use the `highlight function`.

In the document, there is:renderRow function,(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) => renderable
"ListView can be notified when a row is being highlighted by calling highlightRow function. The separators above and below will be hidden when a row is highlighted. The highlighted state of a row can be reset by calling highlightRow(null)."

I read it over and over, then I read the source file of ListView, still I have on clue at all about how to use the highlight function.

Does the highlightRow function is provided for developer to call it when needed? Should developer save the reference of highlightRow if it is needed late on? what parameter should provide when the highlightRow function is called?

Comment: The title just asked how to highlight an item - which has been answered several times, but the post apparently requires a solution using something called the "highlight function".  Not sure the 1st two responses are deserving of a -1 , given we answered your original title in good faith .. "How to highlight an item in a List View".  I have made a couple of small updates to orig.  post so others don't get the same misunderstanding. Cheerios

Answer (score 0):

@tennist, all the other answers are android code. I expect you're looking for a react-native specific solution. I too would love to understand how the highlightRow function is meant to work. If you figure it out, please let me know. I suspect it's similar to the `{rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}` function one adds to the datasource, but I played with it for a second and didn't have any luck. However, I did come up with a work around. Here's how I modified my _renderRow function...

```
_renderRow: function(rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number, highlightRow: func) {

var rowHash = Math.abs(hashCode(rowData));
var highlighted = {};
if(rowID == 5){
    highlighted = {color: 'red'};  
}

return (
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log('[dbug] pressed', rowID)}>
    <View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={[styles.text,highlighted]}>
          {rowData + ' - ' + LOREM_IPSUM.substr(0, rowHash % 301 + 10)}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
);
},
```

Where the secret sauce is this bit...

```
var highlighted = {};
if(rowID == 5){
    highlighted = {color: 'red'};  
}
```

Here, I've arbitrarily decided that rowID 5 should be highlighted, but you can implement whatever logic makes sense for your app there.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code that will highlight your list views selected item.

```java
ListView lstTemplate;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
ArrayList<String> templateNames = new ArrayList<String>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    lstTemplate = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstTamplates);

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, templateNames);
    lstTemplate.setAdapter( listAdapter );
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    lstTemplate.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            if(i == 0) return; // if empty is chosen do nothing

            for (int j = 0; j < adapterView.getChildCount(); j++)
               adapterView.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

           // change the background color of the selected element
           view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
           selectedItemIndex = i;
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I remember having challenges for this as well.  I'm not sure it's the best way to do it .. but here's how I handle highlighting a list item in my Activity class from some code I wrote a year back:

```java
public class MyListActivity extends Activity {

    ListView myListView;
    MyListAdapter myListAdapter;
    View currentlySelectedListItemView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_list);

        myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this);

        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.song_list);

        myListView.setSelection(0);

        myListView.setAdapter(myistAdapter);

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // un-highlight the last item that was selected
                if (currentlySelectedListItemView != null) {
                    currentlySelectedListItemView.setBackgroundColor(
                            Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0)
                    );

                }

                // highlight the item that was selected
                view.setBackgroundColor(
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

                view.getBackground().setAlpha(90);

                currentlySelectedListItemView = view;
            }
        });

    }
```